# Maxima. Function of independent variables as a factor

Tags: function, split, expression, maxima, simplification

Is there a function that selects a function of independent variables as a factor?

For example, if you write:

```
'integrate(2*y*x^2, x);
```

you will get:

```
2*y*'integrate(x^2, x);
```

Like that, only without an integral?:

```
[2*y, x^2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Function: partition (expr, x)

Returns a list of two expressions. They are (1) the factors of expr (if it is a product), the terms of expr (if it is a sum), or the list (if it is a list) which don’t contain x and, (2) the factors, terms, or list which do.

Examples:

```
(%i1) partition (2*a*x*f(x), x);
(%o1)                     [2 a, x f(x)]
(%i2) partition (a+b, x);
(%o2)                      [b + a, 0]
(%i3) partition ([a, b, f(a), c], a); 
(%o3)                  [[b, c], [a, f(a)]]
```